# How to tell if there is a modal UIViewController presented?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

Is there a way to tell whether there is a modal UIViewController presented already, say, before calling `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## iOS 9, 8, 7, 6 & 5

*There are just too many answers to this question, none covering all cases.* Furthermore, despite what you find in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there are **two alternatives** to the now deprecated `modalViewController`:

1. If you need to know if **you** are modal:

   `BOOL modal = nil != [self presentingViewController];`
2. If you need to know if you are **covered** by a modal:

   `BOOL hiddenByModal = nil != [self presentedViewController];`

Answer (score 9):

> **iOS6+ - use presentedViewController:**
>   Since iOS 6, `presentedViewController` should be used instead as the `modalViewController` which has been deprecated

Use the property:

> **Deprecated - modalViewController:**
>   The controller for the active modal view—that is, the view that is temporarily displayed on top of the view managed by the receiver. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *modalViewController
```

Comment: Depreciated in iOS6, use presentedViewController

Answer (score 2):

I usually add a BOOL variable, called something like `isModal`, and I set it after initializing a viewcontroller but before calling `presentModalViewController`. Something like:

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
controller.isModal = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

And then, in MyViewController, before needing to dismiss, I just check:

```
if (isModal) { //dismiss modal }
```

Answer (score 2):

after iOS 5 you should use:

```
if (self.presentingViewController != nil) {

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    //has dismissViewControllerAnimated
    }];
}
```

Edited to change iOS Version

Answer (score 1):

I understand this has been a while but just wanted do add my 2 cents to this matter.

I was in need to identify if there was a modally presented ViewController when the app went to background in order to dismiss it first.

First I made an extension of `UIWindow` to return me the current `ViewController`:

```
extension UIWindow {

    func getCurrentViewController() -> UIViewController? {

        guard let rvc = self.rootViewController else {
            return nil
        }

        if let pvc = rvc.presentedViewController {

            return pvc

        } else if let svc = rvc as? UISplitViewController, svc.viewControllers.count > 0 {

            return svc.viewControllers.last!

        } else if let nc = rvc as? UINavigationController, nc.viewControllers.count > 0 {

            return nc.topViewController!

        } else if let tbc = rvc as? UITabBarController {

            if let svc = tbc.selectedViewController {

                return svc
            }
        }

        return rvc
    }
}
```

Then I went into `appDelegate` and added a test on `applicationDidEnterBackground()`:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if let vc = self.window?.getCurrentViewController() {

        if vc.presentingViewController != nil {

            vc.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is in **Swift 3**